# Autocomplete search box with initial values OnFocus

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following autocomplete functionality integrated on [www.swimstats.net](https://www.swimstats.net):

```
    $("#athleteName1").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 300,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/query_athletes",
                data: { first: $('#athleteName1').val() },
                success: response,
            });
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        console.log('Populate');        
        });
```

I am looking for a solution that presents the user up to 5 previously selected values when the input field `#athleteName1` gets the focus. [Aspired "OnFocus" Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2LJ.png) . The advantage of it is that the user does not have to search again for the athletes he previously searched.

However, as soon as the user starts typing, autocomplete should take over again while the previously selected values disappear.

Any idea how to build a nice and clean solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it does the job:

```
    $("#athleteName1").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        delay: 300,
        source: function (request, response) {
            if ($( "#athleteName1" ).val().length == 0) {
                response(['banana','apple', 'orange']);
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/query_athletes",
                data: { first: $('#athleteName1').val() },
                success: response,
            });
        },
    }).focus(function () {
        if ($( "#athleteName1" ).val().length == 0) {
            $( "#athleteName1" ).autocomplete("search");
            return;
        }
    });
```